# How to add/ modify/ patch altair chart data dynamically?

Tags: python, ipywidgets, altair

I would like to add chart(s), or data to existing chart dynamically (via `ipywidget.interact`) as in the code below (`chart + dotchart`). I get nearly what I want except whole chart gets re-drawn and this causes flickering.

How do I add/ modify/ patch data dynamically and avoid re-drawing whole chart?

Thanks!

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt
from ipywidgets import interact

df = pd.DataFrame({"xval": range(100), "yval": np.random.randint(0,100,100)})
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(x="xval", y="yval",)

def update(x, y):
    dot = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[x], y=[y]))
    dotchart = alt.Chart(dot).mark_point().encode(x="x", y="y", color=alt.value("red"))
    return chart + dotchart 

interact(update, x=(0, 100), y=(0, 100))
# x, y widgets that control position of 'red dot'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to patch data into an Altair chart without re-rendering it is in Javascript, using the [Vega View API](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/). You can see an example of this here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/streaming.html.

I don't know of any prior work on calling the Vega view API from Python, but it's possible in principle.

See the related Altair feature request here: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/426.

Comment: Thank you @jakevdp. Can you please point me in the right direction where roughly can I poke to get access to Vega view API?

Comment: There's no facility in Altair to access the view API. You'd have to create a new renderer that wraps-in communication between the Python backend and the Javascript frontend. There are some projects in the Jupyter ecosystem that do this type of communication, for example [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). If it were easy, someone would have done it already :)

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to do so using the top-level chart configuration methods that altair provides. See here: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/configuration.html

This way you can update many many properties of the current chart without regenerating it.